# Swift / Xcode: How to call a function from within another function in a new .swift file?

Tags: ios, xcode, function

I have created a simple file called GameplayMechanics.swift (with Spritekit imported) and created a test function called checkSpeed().

All I want to do is call this function from within another function my Gameplay.swift file, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

GameplayMechanics.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

func checkSpeedIncrease() {
    print("Checked")
}
```

Gameplay.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

...
...

func checkCounter(number: Int) {
        if number == 10 {
            GameplayMechanics.checkSpeed()
        } else if counter > 10 {
            counter = 0
        }
    }
}
```

I am talking about the checkCounter() function which should call checkSpeed(). The rest is just for illustration included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you set this up makes `checkSpeed` a free function. The way you're calling it makes the compiler expect an object of type `GameplayMechanics` that has a static method `checkSpeed`.

In your case, all you need to do is call the function like this:

```
if number == 10 {
    checkSpeed()
}
```

Comment: Actually, it won't work because there is only a free function named checkSpeedIncrease (), not checkSpeed() :-)